# Ansible Run Analysis tool :Exception during the install of mysqlclient using pip3

Tags: python, gcc, pip, alpine-linux

I want to use a mysql engine/database with ARA instead of the default sqlite engine that comes with the tool in order to have a more robust engine for multiple entries but I am facing an issue that doesn't allow me to acheive this here below the details :

When i specified mysql engine in the settings.yml file for my ARA server I go the following error :

```
~/.ara/server # [ara] Using settings file: /root/.ara/server/settings.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ara/server/__main__.py", line 54, in main
    import MySQLdb  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/bin/ara-manage", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ara/server/__main__.py", line 56, in main
    raise MissingMysqlclientException from e
ara.setup.exceptions.MissingMysqlclientException: The mysqlclient python library must be installed in order to use the MySQL database engine.
```

So I checked if mysqlclient is installed and apparently it is not installed :

```
~/.ara/server # pip3 list installed | grep mysql
```

But when I try to install it I have this huge exceptions block:

```
~/.ara/server # pip3.8 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oq1ay19g/mysqlclient_f0ad3d21508f4b698b4bfb4e7c70b25d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oq1ay19g/mysqlclient_f0ad3d21508f4b698b4bfb4e7c70b25d/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-lm119tma
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oq1ay19g/mysqlclient_f0ad3d21508f4b698b4bfb4e7c70b25d/
  Complete output (41 lines):
  mysql_config --version
  ['10.5.5']
  mysql_config --libs
  ['-L/usr/lib/', '-lmariadb']
  mysql_config --cflags
  ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-I/usr/include/mysql/mysql']
  ext_options:
    library_dirs: ['/usr/lib/']
    libraries: ['mariadb']
    extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
    extra_link_args: []
    include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql', '/usr/include/mysql/mysql']
    extra_objects: []
    define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,0,3,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.0.3')]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oq1ay19g/mysqlclient_f0ad3d21508f4b698b4bfb4e7c70b25d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oq1ay19g/mysqlclient_f0ad3d21508f4b698b4bfb4e7c70b25d/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ksqr0pbp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.8/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oq1ay19g/mysqlclient_f0ad3d21508f4b698b4bfb4e7c70b25d/
    Complete output (41 lines):
    mysql_config --version
    ['10.5.5']
    mysql_config --libs
    ['-L/usr/lib/', '-lmariadb']
    mysql_config --cflags
    ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-I/usr/include/mysql/mysql']
    ext_options:
      library_dirs: ['/usr/lib/']
      libraries: ['mariadb']
      extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
      extra_link_args: []
      include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql', '/usr/include/mysql/mysql']
      extra_objects: []
      define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,0,3,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.0.3')]
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oq1ay19g/mysqlclient_f0ad3d21508f4b698b4bfb4e7c70b25d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oq1ay19g/mysqlclient_f0ad3d21508f4b698b4bfb4e7c70b25d/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ksqr0pbp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.8/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

If I understand the error there is a compilation problem due to the abscence of gcc.
But when I try to unstall gcc7 using pip it doesn't work :

```
~/.ara/server # pip3 install gcc7
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gcc7
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gcc7
```

1- So is my analysis right?

2- What could be the real issue behind this? I mean are there other dependencies that might cause this issue.
any help or tip will be greatly appreciated.

P.S: I am working on alpine distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work installing these two packages :

```
apk add musl-dev gcc
```

Alpine is quite special when it comes to using gcc so this install of musl-dev do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> If I understand the error, there is a compilation problem due to the absence of `gcc`.

I am not familiar with Alpine Linux, but yes, from the errors, it appears you don't have a recognized version of `gcc` (the [GNU Compiler Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection)).

> When I try to install `gcc7` using `pip`, it doesn't work.

While [`gcc7` appears to be a valid Python module](https://pypi.org/project/gcc7/) available via `pip`, it seems to be for [Mac only](https://pypi.org/project/gcc7/#files) at this time.

> Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

The first thing you would likely want to try is installing `gcc` for Alpine Linux yourself (outside of `pip`), assuming it isn't already available.  [Note that the Alpine Linux wiki has some simple instructions on how to do a basic installation of `gcc`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/GCC). They apparently recommend running:

```
apk add build-base
```

to "get started" with `gcc` (i.e. have it and some basic libraries available).

---

*Please be aware that you can still (theoretically) run into other build issues, even if `gcc` is installed correctly.*

---